# popup uiview on uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to display small popup view (just like popup view in iPad but here I want in iPhone) in iPhone with image.

How can I do that with animation?
(something like facebook login)

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout some sample projects on github. You can do this by using core animation.

Comment: in this view i need only uiimage and a button.
there is any simple way?